# Generating a lattice graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I generate the following lattice graph?

[image: **A lattice graph**]

You are welcome to make your own assumptions.

Is it possible to this using `GridGraph`?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. This does not look like a graph. It has no connections.   Do you just want to draw circles at certain coordinates?  If yes, please say so. But in that case, the question has nothing to do with graphs.

Comment: -1 for an ambiguously written question and refusal to correct it. Neither of the answers generate what is called a [lattice graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph).  I'm not sure what you mean by *"You are welcome to make your own assumptions."* but questions on SE should be clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
GridGraph[{4, 4}, EdgeStyle -> White, VertexSize -> Medium, 
 VertexStyle -> White, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.25]]
```

[image]

You can also use `` GraphComputation`EmptyGraph ``:

```
Framed @ Show[GraphComputation`EmptyGraph[Range[16]],
 ImageMargins -> Scaled[.05], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using GraphLayout:

```
Graph[Range[16], {}, 
 GraphLayout -> {"VertexLayout" -> {"GridEmbedding", 
     "Dimension" -> {4, 4}}, "PackingLayout" -> None}, 
 VertexSize -> Medium, VertexStyle -> White, PlotRangePadding -> 1, 
 Frame -> True]
```

You can modify "Dimension" to change the shape:

```
Graph[Range[16], {}, 
 GraphLayout -> {"VertexLayout" -> {"GridEmbedding", 
     "Dimension" -> {2, 8}}, "PackingLayout" -> None}, 
 VertexSize -> Medium, VertexStyle -> White, PlotRangePadding -> 1, 
 Frame -> True]
```